How to integrate decimal numbers to be displayed in the MUI Textifeld but not to change the value
I want to apply that the number to be displayed in MUI Textfield form to be in decimal display, is there a possible way to integrate mask input, so input value does not alter as decimal but just to be displayed as decimal
 <TextField
      type="number"
      fullWidth
      helperText={errorMessage}
      error={!!errorMessage}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: startAdornment === "percentage" && (
          <InputAdornment position="start">%</InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
    />


You can use react-number-format library. In your case you can do it like this:
import { NumericFormat } from 'react-number-format';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const NumericFormatCustom = React.forwardRef(function NumericFormatCustom(
  props,
  ref
) {
  const { onChange, startAdornment, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <NumericFormat
      {...other}
      getInputRef={ref}
      onValueChange={(values) => {
        onChange({
          target: {
            name: props.name,
            value: values.value,
          },
        });
      }}
      thousandSeparator
      valueIsNumericString
      prefix={startAdornment === 'percentage' ? '%' : undefined}
    />
  );
});


<TextField
    label="MUI Number Format with Prefix"
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    fullWidth
    helperText={errorMessage}
    error={!!errorMessage}
    InputProps={{
      inputComponent: NumericFormatCustom,
    }}
    inputProps={{
      startAdornment: 'percentage',
    }}
    variant="standard"
  />

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example.
